# Python: How can I capture the boot logs through SSH on a remote Linux machine?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko, boot

Objective: I want to write a Python test script to execute a reboot command through SSH on a remote Linux machine, capture the boot logs and check if the boot is successful.

Problem: I am able to send a reboot command using Paramiko and the machine reboots as expected, but I couldn't capture the boot logs and print them out. My code also seems to run without waiting for the boot process to finish.

Here is part of my code:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
except paramiko.SSHException as e:
    ssh.get_transport().auth_none(username)  # without password

# execute reboot and capture the boot logs
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("/sbin/reboot")
print(stdout.readlines())
print(stderr.readlines())

# check if reboot is done
exit_status = ''
msg = ''
while True:
    if stdout_channel.exit_status_ready():
        exit_status = ssh.stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
        print("Exit status: %s" % exit_status)
        break
    time.sleep(10)

ssh.close()
if exit_status == 0:
    print("Reboot successful")
else:
    print(Reboot not successful")
```

Logs are not captured and the following output is printed out before the machine finishing rebooting:

```
[]
[]
Exit status: 0
Reboot successful
```

Questions:

a) How can I capture the boot logs?

b) How to properly check for status after boot process is completed? Alternatively, I think I can ssh again and simply run a command after waiting some time for it to reboot.

Comment: While the machine boots, `ssh` might not be available.

Comment: Is there any alternative to `ssh` for me to capture the boot logs up to login prompt?

Comment: `dmesg` might work, after the reboot.

Comment: If you run `reboot` in SSH terminal, do you see the boot log? I guess you don't, or do you?

Comment: Nope, I don't. I might try serial, idea from this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73503469/python3-10-4-serial-readline-not-displaying-prompts)

Answer (score 0):

1. you need /var/log/boot.log or /var/log/dmesg
2. You need monitoring. Generally, for LAN you need something like zabbix, but it is to much for 2 hosts. Other way is any [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359989/formatting-slack-message-posted-from-shell-script) for sending message from remote host to your log server or messenger(using messenger API) or vice versa. For your script you can make  systemd [Unit service](https://www.shellhacks.com/systemd-service-file-example/) for run it after/before anything.